# C++ Multi-Dimensional Array saving/loading to file error

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, ifstream, ofstream

I've been working on this C++ project for roughly 2 weeks now and I'm stumped on a couple things regarding 2D Arrays. To start off here is the code I wrote as of now:

http://pastebin.com/vCsz947Q

I decided to provide this as a pastebin link due to the fact that it's rather large (it uses 8 functions) and I thought it would save space in this post. I'm new to this site so I apologize if there's a better way that I'm not aware of.

*The Problem:*

When I go to save my "char seating" array to a .dat file using the "save seats" function that I created, I get a file that gives me the following garbage character " Ì " instead of the intended ' # ' (for open seats) or ' * ' (if a seat is bought).

My functions will save the intended amount of rows (15) and columns (30) despite this though. Also an asterisk will be placed when I go to "purchase a seat" in this program in the file. Additionally my program loads the files as intended, except for the fact that... Well... There's garbage data stored in the seat array.

I feel like this relates to another problem I'm having where if I go to the "purchase seats" function and I say to purchase a seat, it should replace a # with a *, but it doesn't, yet in the saved file it will show an asterisk in the intended spot... Which is very strange.

I have absolutely no idea why this occurs, and what's frustrating is this one thing that's preventing me from finishing this program. I want to believe that my original array in int main that's being called by other functions isn't being updated properly, but I don't know, which is why I came here to seek assistance.

Thank you for your assistance whoever can help.

Comment: Whether you put it in your question or host it on another website, that is still an unreasonable amount of code to expect anyone to read. Produce a *minimal*, reproducible example and put that in your question.

Comment: I apologize, I'll refrain from doing this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for a start you have some undefined behaviour here inside your `displaySeatingChart (char displaySeats[ ][30], float displayPrices[ ])` function with the following:

```
const int rowDisplay = 15;
const int colDisplay = 30;
```

as later within one of your loops you have

```
cout << displaySeats[rowDisplay][colDisplay];
```

which is clearly reading beyond the array bounds since in `main()` you define

```
const int rowMain = 15;
const int colMain = 30;
char seating[rowMain][colMain];
float seatPrices[15];
```

and pass both `seating` and `seatPrices` to the `displaySeats` function. There may well be other problems with your code but this at least is a clear example of undefined behaviour. Consider stepping through the code with a debugger to get a clearer idea of the source of the issue.

On another note given that you are working with C++ consider working with `std::vector` instead of arrays. This will give you more scope to ascertain the dimensions of the items that arrays that you are working with from within your utility functions and result in less potential for errors in array access.

Comment: Thank you for your response first of all, this is all very informative. You mention "undefined behavior". This is actually my first time hearing about that term, so I apologize if it takes me a little longer to catch on but... What would be a good example of a solution to undefined behavior? Also I'll take a look at the debugger as you mentioned.

Comment: @Neutral - You are welcome. If you are new to programming, it is incredibly useful to learn how to use a debugger. If nothing else it will give you the power to analyse your code at run time. If you take the time to learn this skill, I guarantee you will not consider it time wasted. Even if it does not make the problem obvious it will allow you to get closer to the source - and then perhaps post a new more concise question that is more likely to generate a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Yea I'm brand new to programming, so a lot of this is all very new to me still. With that being said I never got the opportunity to mess with the debugger, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Neutral This is your first post so don't be disheartened by any criticism or downvotes. Read the site FAQ and take heed. This place is a fantastic resource if you formulate your questions in a manner consistent with the FAQ

Comment: I followed your instructions and I finally realized that my problem was what you mentioned. I indeed had some undefined behavior. I switched up my array check so that in most of my loops I would look for i and j, not the const ints. Thank you for your help!